# How to open a new window with a one-to-many connection?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to implement data transfer to a new window when communicating one to many?

I need to pass the statistics values of the selected object in a new window.

Below, I gave an example of how I open a window with one value (one selected object has one contact value):

```
private void ClickContact(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Contact contact = new Contact(SelectedCardhall.CardPavNavigation);
    contact.Show();
}
```

But I need to show a window with statistics (one object has several different values).
How and what values should I pass for the new statistics window?

[image: That's the database]
Tbl_cardhall - table with all information about objects. tbl_stat - table with statistics data.

Comment: Pass an appropriate view model object to the DataContext property of the Contact window.

Comment: Here is an example [@github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-76388000-WpfMultipleWindows) with multiple windows, viewmodels and how to pass parameters